I don't know how it works to execute events when clicking buttons on a calculator from a code I found
I found this calculator code on Github and wanted to know how it works to execute events when clicking buttons.
The "button_click" method appears in the code, but I don't understand how it works.
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30, borderwidth=5)
entry.grid( columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)


# These variables are used to keep track of the current row and column numbers
# when placing buttons in the grid layout.
row_num = 1
col_num = 0

buttons = [
    "7", "8", "9", "/",
    "4", "5", "6", "*",
    "1", "2", "3", "-",
    "0", ".", "=", "+",
    "C" 
]
def button_click(event):
    text = event.widget.cget("text")
    if text == "=":
        try:
            result = eval(entry.get())
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)     # tk. END refers to the position after the existing text
            entry.insert(tk.END, str(result))
        except Exception as e:
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            entry.insert(tk.END, "Error")   
    elif text == "C":
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    else:
        entry.insert(tk.END, text)

for button_text in buttons:
    button = tk.Button(root, text=button_text, padx=20, pady=10)
    button.grid(row=row_num, column=col_num, padx=5, pady=5)
    button.bind("<Button-1>", button_click)
    col_num += 1
    if col_num > 3:
        col_num = 0
        row_num += 1

root.mainloop()

On line 40, the method appears, but I don't know why it is without the parentheses.
Could someone explain it to me?

The best way to understand source code is to go to the documentation (or the tkinter tutorial might be even better in this case). You are asking about line 40, which calls the bind() function of the button object. button is an instance of tkinter.Button. Here is the exact link to the part where bind() is mentioned.
If you're not familiar with the general concept of event binding, it refers to when you connect (or bind) a function (or event) to a user action--typically clicking a button or pressing a key.
You mentioned that the function appears without parentheses. Parentheses after a function name indicates calling the function. But in Python, functions are "First Class". They are objects like everything else so you can treat a funciton like any other object--by assigning it to a variable, passing it to another function, returning it from another function, or storing it in data structures. Line 40 passes the button_click function itself as an argument to bind().
Here is an example of what you can do with functions in Python:
def double(x):
    return x*2

# assign function to variable
twice = double
twice(3)  # returns 6

# pass function as parameter
def print_results(f, value)
    result = f(value)
    print(result)
    return result

print_results(double, 5)  # prints and returns 10

